# how to make this python code look cleaner?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, code-cleanup

I've recently wrote 'hangman' in python. Then added few things and now I am trying to clean this up a bit.
Any ideas how to get rid of these two *while (...) true* statements?
Also I think there's too many *if (...) else* statements.
Any tips and other suggestions would be appreciated :)

```
word = "stackoverflow"
user_word = []
used_letters = []
 
def find_indexes(word, letter):
    indexes = []
    
    for index, letter_in_word in enumerate(word):
        if letter == letter_in_word:
            indexes.append(index)
    return indexes
 
for _ in word:
    user_word.append("_")
 
 
while True:
    try:
        no_of_tries = int(input("Enter number of tries: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter numeric value :)")
        
while True:
    
    letter = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
    if letter.isalpha():
        if len(letter) == 1:
            used_letters.append(letter)
            found_indexes = find_indexes(word, letter)
            if len(found_indexes) == 0:
                print("There's no such letter in your word :(")
                no_of_tries -= 1
                print("Tries left: ", no_of_tries,)
                
                if no_of_tries == 0:
                    print("It was nice...to meet you")
                    # sys.exit()
                    
            else:
                for index in found_indexes:
                    user_word[index] = letter
                whole_word = "".join(user_word)
                if whole_word == word:
                    print("WOW, VICTORY!!! :D")
                print("".join(user_word))
        
            print("Used letters: ", used_letters )
        else:
            print("Enter ONE letter")
    else:
        print("Enter letter")
```

Comment: If you don't get a big response here, you could try moving this question over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is even continuing if the word is complete or the chances are over.

Use a variable in the while loop:-

```py
playing = True
while playing:
```

And to over the thing use this:-

```py
if no_of_tries == 0:
  print("It was nice...to meet you")
  playing = False
```

```py
if whole_word == word:
  print("WOW, VICTORY!!! :D")
  playing = False
```

Comment: I was thinking of adding `import sys`  and then comment out the line `sys.exit`  but I like your solution too. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, if you like it please consider upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Too broad question, perhaps.

A good rule is to handle trivial cases first and do the main processing last:

```
while True:
    letter = input("Enter a letter: ").lower()
    if not letter.isalpha():
        print("Enter letter")
        continue
    if len(letter) != 1:
        print("Enter ONE letter")
        continue

    used_letters.append(letter)
    ... etc ...
```

Notice how the indentation level has decreased.